# Regular expression for counting line which starts with @ and contains a tab

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a regular expression for find all the lines which starts with @ and has a tab '\t' in some random position.

for example:

@This is example line (a tab char) which has tab in somewhere midle.

I tried googleing but nothing seems of my help right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this regular expression:

```
^@.*\t
```

And enable multiline option, i.e.: `(?m)^@.*\t`

Comment: [^\t]* is faster than .* if you're hitting a ton of text.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this: -

```
"^@[^\t]*\t[^\t]*$"  // If there is only 1 tab character
```

or

```
"^@.*\t.*$"   // If there can be more than one tab characters.
```

Comment: @Chetan.. What language are you using? As the first version should also have worked.

Comment: @RohitJain, And if line contains more than one `\t`?

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk.. I thought it was explicit from the question that there would be only one tab character. But if there is more then the 2nd one will work.

Answer (score 0):

See if this expression works:

```
^@.*\t.*$
```